# R Server: install.packages() certificate error

Tags: r, ssl, curl, certificate, artifactory

Trying to install R packages from an artifactory server. The CRAN plug in is installed, I can curl the contents using the default CA on the VM however when running this command:

`install.packages("*PACKAGE*", repos="*ARTIFACTORY SERVER*")`

I get the following output:

`Installing package into ‘/home/qbeadmin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html`

This looks like R Server is not using the default ca-bundle.crt but i dont know how to configure this

Thanks in advance,

Kind Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure the location of the CA bundles used by cURL by the setting the [CURL_CA_BUNDLE](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) environment variable in the [Renviron](https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#renviron) file.
This is documented in the [download.file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html) documentation.

Comment: Thanks heaps, I couldn't find where to set that variable for R!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can download the package first, and install it.
For example with Cairo package :

```
curl -kO https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Cairo_1.5-8.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL Cairo_1.5-8.tar.gz
```